# ValueError: time data '2013/05/24 07:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x,y = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('noneventEventdetect.csv'))
for line in csv_reader:
    x.append(line[1])
    T = dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #print(T)
    y.append(T)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(y,x) 
fig.autofmt_xdate()



plt.show()
```

Example CSV data (python3.4):

> 24/5/2013 7:00:00     1
>
> 24/5/2013 7:00:00     2
>
> 24/5/2013 7:00:00     3
>
> 24/5/2013 7:00:00     4
>
> 24/5/2013 7:00:00     5
>
> 24/5/2013 7:00:00     6

This  error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Kitravee\Desktop\New folder (4)\sdf.py", line 12, in
>
> ```
> T = dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
>
> ```
> tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
>
> ```
> (data_string, format))
> ```
>
> ValueError: time data '2013/05/24 07:00:00' does not match format
>   '%d-%m-%Y
>
> %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code in the question, the error message (your actual code), the csv data, the input data from the error use different formats: `%Y-%m-%d`, `%d-%m-%Y`, `%d/%m/%Y`, and `%Y/%m/%d` correspondingly (notice that it is four different formats).

Comment: You might be interested in `python-dateutil` library. It provides the `dateutil.parse` method which automatically discovers most of the used formats for dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time in your title is in a different format than the one in the file you provided, and both of them do not match the format.

For the time in the file you need `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`, for the time in your title you need `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: this is my error: ValueError: time data '2013/05/24 07:00:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

Comment: The format in your error is not what I suggested in my answer,  so please read it and try it :)

Comment: ohh I got it thank you very much this is my first time to ask question if i make some mistake I'm very sorry